# Not able to login to my instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I created an instance of ubuntu ec2 yesterday and I was trying to configure it and I stopped the serer before going home last night, when I tried log on to the same instance using ssh from my ubuntu I am getting an error which says connection timed out. I am not able to login to the instance now

Comment: What do you mean by you stopped the server?. You shut it down?

Comment: Yup I shut it down but I realized that every time i reboot my server aws allocates dynamic DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you stopped the instance, and the instance was ebs-backed then you should be able to start it using the ec2 api.

Describe the instance using the `ec2-describe-instances/instance-attributes` api and use `ec2-run-instance` start it. Once started, use the above api to retrieve the public dns name.
Using this you should be able to login to that same machine again.

if you have terminated an instance-store based virtual machine, then you can kiss it goodbye.